# How do I capitalize the first word after each period, question mark or exclamation point?

Tags: substitute

I would like to know the proper substitution command in vi that would accomplish this.

Comment: Did you meant capitalizying the first word or first character of the first word?

Answer (score 8):

```
%s;[.?!]\_s*\zs\<\w\+\>;\U&;g
```

This is a normal vim substitute command with `;` as *separation character*; you can use other characters beside the default `/` as separation character, as long as it does not appear in the expression.

```
%s        : Do substitute command on the entire buffer

[.?!]     : match every . or ? or ! and
\_s*      : match every whitespace including newline after it if there is any, and
\zs       : start the match from here and
\<\w\+\>  : select first word

\U&       : then make it capitalize (or use \u& to only capitalize first character)

g         : globally
```

Comment: What do the semi colons represent?

Comment: @JohnBradowski, one can use other delimiters like `; #` instead of usual `/`

Comment: There is often a space between a punctuation mark and the following word, so your command could be `%s;[.?!]\s\?\<\w\+\>;\U&;g` to handle these white-spaces.

Comment: @statox To be useful, you'd presumably also want the regexp to handle newlines, paragraph breaks, etc.

Comment: @Sundeep, tanx for explanation. answer edited.

Comment: @statox , Tanx for hint. Edited.

Comment: @JohnBradowski, answer edited to reflect comments.

Comment: @dNitro thanks a lot for this answer. I just have one question. Where can I find the vim help related to `\u&` and `\U&` ? I understand approximately what it does, but I would like to read the official documentation for it. And `:h \u&` returns nothing, even searching for `/\\u&` in `change.txt` and `pattern.txt`. Thanks in advance !